# Beta reduction Lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to reduce the following using beta reduction:

`(λx.x x) (λx. λy.x x)`

I am getting stuck after the first substitution since it seems to be giving `(λx. λy.x x)(λx. λy.x x)`  which would end in kind of a loop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an illustration of the evaluation

```
beta reduction 1
(λx.x x) (λx.λy.x x)              →β x [x := (λx.λy.x x)]
(λx.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x))

beta reduction 2
(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x)           →β x [x := (λx.λy.x x)]
(λx.λy.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x))

result
λy.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x)
```

Now we have reached Weak Head Normal Form – ie, we have a lambda `λy` without any arguments to apply it to.

To get to Head Normal Form, we can attempt to reduce *under* the lambda ...

```
reduction 1
λy.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x)       →β x [x := (λx.λy.x x)]
λy.(λx.λy.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x))

reduction 2 ...
λy.λy.(λx.λy.x x) (λx.λy.x x)
```

Ok, we can immediately see that this pattern will repeat itself. Each time we try to reduce under the lambda, the result gets wrapped in another `λy`.

So, this particular lambda expression does not have a Head Normal Form – ie, the evaluation of this expression (when applied to an argument) will never terminate; it will never reach Normal Form.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong.

The expression
`(λx.x x) (λx. λy.x x)` beta-reduces in one step to `(λx. λy.x x)(λx. λy.x x)`, which beta-reduces to `λy.(λx. λy.x x)(λx. λy.x x)` and then to `λy.λy.(λx. λy.x x)(λx. λy.x x)`.
In every step, each new expression is the same as before, but contained in a new abstraction.

In Lambda Calculus, the reduction process may not terminate. In other words, programs may not terminate (like in any turing-complete programming language).

Another example of this is the term `Ω = (λx.x x)(λx.x x)`